# Про поведение подстановочного типа

Tags: java

```
static class A<T> {

    T t;

    public void set(T t){

    }

    public T get(){
        return t;
    }
}

public static void aSetter(A<?> a){
    a.set(a.get());
}
```

> Error:(22, 10) java: method set in class Main.A cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: capture#1 of ?
>     found: java.lang.Object
>     reason: actual argument java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? by method invocation conversion

Я читал про подстановочные типы и вот что не понял : почему при компиляции метод get тоже не возращает заглушку *capture* ?
Похоже, я не совсем понимаю механизм их создания

Answer (score 1):

Если почитать документацию по `wildcard` в [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)
То в ней есть пример аналогичный вашему:

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
```

> Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot
>   add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the
>   element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?,
>   it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would
>   have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what
>   type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null,
>   which is a member of every type.

Т.е. компилятор не знает какой тип объекты ожидается и соответственно ругается на все типы. В вашем случае даже на `a.get()`, потому что он возвращает как минимум `Object`, а не заглушку(*capture*) как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем заглушка нужна, возвращал бы все Object. фактически компилятор , видя wildcard пытается всячески защитить объект от возможного изменения посредством некорректного типа( в данном случае возможности передачи неверного типа в гет)

Answer (score 1):

Каждый вопросик — это разный тип. Чтобы два вопросика промэпились на один и тот же тип, надо дать ему имя — задать генерик-параметр для метода:

```
public static <T> void aSetter(A<T> a){
    a.set(a.get());
}
```

Comment: Я знаю. Вообще не совсем четко понимаю зачем нужны wild cards . Если можно вместо них писать Имя

Comment: @voipp, вопросик нужен, когда вас имя вообще не волнует. Например, вы не собираетесь вызывать методы с генерик-параметрами или возвращаемым типом. Скажем, вы принимаете на вход `Collection<?> c` и вызываете только `c.size()`. Тогда вам действительно плевать на тип коллекции и не нужно заводить лишний генерик-параметр. Но один вопросик никогда не равен другому.